# duplicate symbol Error : RadioTunes framework and Opentok.Framework

Tags: ios, ios6, video-streaming, internet-radio

I have successful implemented `RadioTunes` API in my ios project for Live radio streaming.
For that,i have make user of `RadioTunes.Framewrok,libavcodec.a,libavformat.a,libavutil.a,libswresample.a.`

It is working perfectly in my project.

Now i want to integrate `OpenTok.framework`(from TokBox.com) for Live Video Chat api.But When I am trying to include this openTok.framework in my project,i am getting following dupicate syntax error :

```
duplicate symbol _avcodec_register_all in:
    /Volumes/Drive A/Chirag/iOS project/Dolphin7-iOS-Src-v.1.6/Opentok.framework/Opentok(allcodecs.o)
    /Volumes/Drive A/Chirag/iOS project/Dolphin7-iOS-Src-v.1.6/External/ffmpeg/lib/libavcodec.a(allcodecs.o)
duplicate symbol _ff_prefetch_arm in:
    /Volumes/Drive A/Chirag/iOS project/Dolphin7-iOS-Src-v.1.6/Opentok.framework/Opentok(dsputil_arm.o)
    /Volumes/Drive A/Chirag/iOS project/Dolphin7-iOS-Src-v.1.6/External/ffmpeg/lib/libavcodec.a(dsputil_arm.o)
duplicate symbol _ff_put_pixels16_arm in:
    /Volumes/Drive A/Chirag/iOS project/Dolphin7-iOS-Src-v.1.6/Opentok.framework/Opentok(dsputil_arm.o)
    /Volumes/Drive A/Chirag/iOS project/Dolphin7-iOS-Src-v.1.6/External/ffmpeg/lib/libavcodec.a(dsputil_arm.o)
duplicate symbol _ff_put_pixels8_arm in:
    /Volumes/Drive A/Chirag/iOS project/Dolphin7-iOS-Src-v.1.6/Opentok.framework/Opentok(dsputil_arm.o)
    /Volumes/Drive A/Chirag/iOS project/Dolphin7-iOS-Src-v.1.6/External/ffmpeg/lib/libavcodec.a(dsputil_arm.o)


........
duplicate symbol _ff_get_cpu_flags_arm in:
    /Volumes/Drive A/Chirag/iOS project/Dolphin7-iOS-Src-v.1.6/Opentok.framework/Opentok(cpu.o)
    /Volumes/Drive A/Chirag/iOS project/Dolphin7-iOS-Src-v.1.6/External/ffmpeg/lib/libavutil.a(cpu.o)
duplicate symbol _av_get_channel_layout_nb_channels in:
    /Volumes/Drive A/Chirag/iOS project/Dolphin7-iOS-Src-v.1.6/Opentok.framework/Opentok(audioconvert.o)
    /Volumes/Drive A/Chirag/iOS project/Dolphin7-iOS-Src-v.1.6/External/ffmpeg/lib/libavutil.a(audioconvert.o)
duplicate symbol _av_get_channel_layout_string in:
    /Volumes/Drive A/Chirag/iOS project/Dolphin7-iOS-Src-v.1.6/Opentok.framework/Opentok(audioconvert.o)
    /Volumes/Drive A/Chirag/iOS project/Dolphin7-iOS-Src-v.1.6/External/ffmpeg/lib/libavutil.a(audioconvert.o)
duplicate symbol _av_strcasecmp in:
    /Volumes/Drive A/Chirag/iOS project/Dolphin7-iOS-Src-v.1.6/Opentok.framework/Opentok(avstring.o)
    /Volumes/Drive A/Chirag/iOS project/Dolphin7-iOS-Src-v.1.6/External/ffmpeg/lib/libavutil.a(avstring.o)


duplicate symbol _av_register_all in:
    ......
    /Volumes/Drive A/Chirag/iOS project/Dolphin7-iOS-Src-v.1.6/External/ffmpeg/lib/libavformat.a(utils.o)
duplicate symbol _ff_read_packet in:
    /Volumes/Drive A/Chirag/iOS project/Dolphin7-iOS-Src-v.1.6/Opentok.framework/Opentok(utils.o)
    /Volumes/Drive A/Chirag/iOS project/Dolphin7-iOS-Src-v.1.6/External/ffmpeg/lib/libavformat.a(utils.o)
........
ld: 787 duplicate symbols for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

here,"External/ffmpeg/lib/" is required directory for RadioTunes.Framework.

Now, I can not remove `RadioTunes` realted framework and also want to add `OpenTok.framwork`.

how to do that work?

Can anyone help me,how to remove this duplicate syntax error but need both RadioTune.framework and OpenTok.framework.

Comment: hello , i want to implement radioTunes sdk but little issue .
how to play .wav file in radio sdk .thanks in advance plz help me :)

Answer (score 0):

If i understand clearly the problem go to the "Compile Sources" section in "Build Phases" and simply remove the duplicate entry for the ffmpeg file.

Comment: Opentok.framework has a build of FFmpeg in it, but the necessary codecs for the RadioTunes dependency might not be compiled in. Gabriele is mostly correct. The first step is to remove the ffmpeg static libs from the build by dropping the libav*.a files for ffmpeg from your "Link Binary with Libraries" task.